# How to handle "matching query does not exist" when getting an object

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

When I want to select objects with a get() function like

```
personalProfile = World.objects.get(ID=personID)
```

If get function doesn't return find a value, a "matching query does not exist." error occurs.

If I don't need this error, I'll use try and except function

```
try:
   personalProfile = World.objects.get(ID=personID)
except:
   pass
```

But I think this is not the best way since I use

```
except:
      pass
```

Please recommend some idea or code sample to fight with this issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do if it doesn't exist..

Theres [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

> Calls get() on a given model manager, but it raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

```
get_object_or_404(World, ID=personID)
```

Which is very close to the try except code you currently do.

Otherwise theres [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
personalProfile, created = World.objects.get_or_create(ID=personID)
```

Although, If you choose to continue with your current approach, at least make sure the except is localised to the correct error and then do something with that as necessary

```
try:
   personalProfile = World.objects.get(ID=personID)
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
```

<sub>The above try/except handle is similar to what is found in the docs for get_object_or_404...</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this help.
I try this and getting error 
because I haven't import a Http404 
Then fix this by 
"from django.http import Http404"
and perfect!

Answer (score 4):

A `get_or_none()` function has been [proposed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2659), [multiple](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11352) [times](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17546) now. The rejection notice is *feature creep*, which you might or might not agree with. The functionality is present --with slightly different semantics-- in the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#first) queryset method.

But first things first:

The manager throws `World.DoesNotExist`, a specialized subclass of [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) when a `World` object was not found:

```
try:
    personalProfile = World.objects.get(ID=personID)
except World.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

There's also [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) which raises a `Http404` exception when the object was not found.

You can also roll your own `get_or_none()`. A possible implementation could be:

```
def get_or_none(queryset, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Note that this still raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` when more than one matching object is found. If you always want the first object regardless of any others, you can simplify using `first()`, which returns `None` when the queryset is empty:

```
def get_or_none(queryset, *args, **kwargs):
    return queryset.filter(*args, **kwargs).first()
```

Note however, for this to work reliably, you need a proper order for objects, because in the presence of multiple objects `first()` might be non-deterministic (it probably returns the first object from the database index used to filter the query and neither indexes not the underlying tables need be sorted or even have a repeatable order).

Use both, however, only when the use of the object to retrieve is strictly optional for the further program flow. When failure to retrieve an object is an error, use `get_object_or_404()`. When an object should be created when it does not exist, use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). In those cases, both are better suited to simplify program flow.

Comment: The [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#first) method added in Django 1.6 is pretty similar to `get_or_none`. Note that you're not handling `MultipleObjectsReturned` in your method. The `first()` method simply takes the first element, and ignores the rest.

Comment: @Alasdair Not handling `MultipleObjectsReturned` is quite intentional. However, yes, `get_or_none()` can be simplified to use `first()`. Have you checked how that affects the generated SQL queries?

Comment: My point is that although the tickets you linked to were closed as won't fix, the feature was eventually added, but with a different name. `MyModel.objects.filter(**kwargs).first()` does the same thing `get_object_or_none(MyModel, **kwargs)`, unless you really care about `MultipleObjectsReturned` (which I expect most of the time you don't). I haven't examined the SQL, but I expect it will be pretty similar, perhaps with some differences with `limit`.

Comment: @Alasdair Hmm, I think that depends on what semantics you want. I actually do care about `MultipleObjectsReturned`. When there are multiple objects that match the filter and I want only one, `first()` might return any of them non-deterministically depending if the underlying queryset is sorted or not. If prefer django to bark at me loud and clear when that happens ;).

Comment: Sure, I understand that handling `MultipleObjectsReturned` is important sometimes, which is why I mentioned it to begin with. In those cases, you need a try except block to handle it, and in that case I'd rather use `get()`, rather than a `get_or_none()` shortcut that handles one possible exception but not the other.

Comment: @Alasdair We might have different use cases, then. I have `get_or_none()` in a few loader scripts mostly as a substitute for `get_or_create()` where the retrieval needs different arguments than the associated create (i.e. something like get_or_create_with_default_args). In those cases, no object is okay, but multiple objects is a fatal error. I also just checked and I actually use it *twice* in non-script code, so you are probably right and the use case is quite special.

Comment: I think we're pretty much in agreement, you obviously know your use cases better than me. I didn't mean to start a huge comment thread, just wanted to point out `first()` for future readers :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) mentioned you could use the built in [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#first) method.
It returns the object if it exists or None if it's not

```
personalProfile = World.objects.filter(ID=personID).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works perfect

```
World.objects.get_or_create(ID=personID)
```

Thanks to @Sayse