# django 1.8- if form entry query result does't match database, display alert message on same page, instead of "None" or raise exception page

Tags: python, django

I am grateful to the answers below, but sorry I still didn't resolve this issue maybe I didn't understand them correctly. Therefore I put a bounty for this for clearer answer.

After user entering some information in the form, these information works as a query to filter the database to get the result, if there is no corresponding record in the database, how could I have an alert displaying on the current page or redirected page alerting users "No corresponding data".

[image]

Take an example as picture: if user enters "EU" and "India", for sure there is no corresponding record in the database. And the form allows the user to leave the fields blank.

I used to use raise ValidationError, if query result doesn't match database, it will go to a yellow "Exception" page which is not user-friendly. I want to display an error message on the SAME form page right after submitting it :

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages

class InputFormView(FormView):
template_name = 'entryform.html'
form_class = EntryForm

def get_success_url(self):
    params = {
        'department': self.request.POST.get('company'),
        'person': self.request.POST.get('region')
    }
    return ''.join([reverse('final'), '?', urllib.urlencode(params.items())])

class FinalView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'XXX'
    template_name = 'XXX.html'
    model = Final

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = InputForm(self.request.GET)        
        if form.is_valid():
            department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            person = form.cleaned_data['person']

            if department !="" and person !="":
                if Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person).exists():
                    queryset=Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person)
                    return queryset
                else:
                    msg="no corresponding data exists!"
                    form.add_error('department', msg)
                    form.add_error('person', msg)

            elif department =="" and person !="":
                if Final.objects.filter(person=person).exists():
                    queryset=Final.objects.filter(person=person)
                    return queryset
                else:
                    msg="no corresponding data exists!"
                    form.add_error('department', msg)
                    form.add_error('person', msg)

            elif ........


        else:     #if form not valid
            messages.error(request, "Error")

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        query_set = self.get_queryset()
        if query_set is not None:
            context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

**html**

```
 <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      {{ formset.errors }}
      {{ formset.non_field_errors }}
      {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
      {{ form.non_field_errors }}     
     ......                   
        <!--select department-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select department:
            {{ form.department }}
                {% for department in form.department.choices %}                    
                     <option value="department" name= "department" id="id_department">{{department}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>     

..........same for person.....                    

        <!--submit-->
        <div class="button" id="btnShow"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

        </div>
 </form>
```

If I don't use the ValidationError method, it will redirect to result page showing everything as "None". But I want to display an alert message. I saw there was an ajax example online, which is a little bit complicated. Is there any easier way to realize it？

Thanks in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How to handle “matching query does not exist” when getting an object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33119507/1324033)

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, but I don't want the error message showing in another page explained in this post, I just want this error alert appearing on the same form template after clicking ”submit". And also I allow some fields to be blank by user, then in this case I shouldn't use form.addError() as well. Right?

Comment: That page shows you the different options you have when getting an object. Although using `form.errors` is the correct way to go

Comment: @Sayse, "form.addError()" is "If its value is None the error will be treated as a non-field error as returned by Form.non_field_errors()." But I allow some fields to be left blank by user, then in this case I couldn't use form.addError() right?

Comment: If you're using `add_error` then you're doing your own error handling which means *you* are choosing which errors to propagate. If they aren't required then you have no need to add an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the FinalView should just filter on the GET parameters?

Do you really need the form if that's the case? I it seem like you want to present "no corresponding data exists!" if no result is yielded?
generic Listview automatically populates self.object_list (or the context_object_name) from get_queryset so a simple check object_list.exists() should be enough in code or template to render the error msg...

To do a simple filter I'll provide an example of a technique I usually use transformed for your example:

```
class FinalView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FinalView, self).get_queryset()
        filter_fields = ('department', 'person')  # the fields to filter on
        query_dict = {}  # filter query
        for param in self.request.GET:  # iterate all params
            if param in filter_fields:  # is param a filter we want to use?
                value = self.request.GET.get(param)
                if value:  # Have value? otherwise ignore
                    query_dict[param] = value
        return qs.filter(**query_dict)  # Execute filter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(FinalView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.object_list.exists():  # Did we get objects? (this can also be done directly in template)
           kwargs['error_msg'] = 'no corresponing data exist!'
       else:
           kwargs["sales"] = self.object_list.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
       # Re-populate form if we want that
       kwargs['form'] = InputForm(initial=self.request.GET)
       return kwargs
```

Don't know if it fits your requirements. But is an alternative solution.

**Elaboration of forms in django:**
The forms in django is used (among other things)to validate input data and create the appropriate python types from the fields. (I.e IntegerField will be an integer etc). [Roles for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#django-s-role-in-forms)

In this case the data is used to filter a queryset. The data it self is valid but not the result *using* the data.

The "roles" for the ListView and form are important:
The view filters the queryset, the django form validates input data.

The view should handle if we're not happy with the result after executing the filter, the django form should handle if the input data is bad. (I.e bad format, empty fields or department must no be empty if person is filled etc).

Based on the question we know the input to FinalView will be strings or empty. (The self.request.GET is always strings or empty), the need of a django form here might just complicate things?

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck with django <1.7 you can use `self._errors.add`(thanks to @Sayse). If you're on django 1.7 or newer you can use [`Form.add_error()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error):

> This method allows adding errors to specific fields from within the
>   Form.clean() method, or from outside the form altogether; for instance
>   from a view.
>
> The field argument is the name of the field to which the errors should
>   be added. If its value is None the error will be treated as a
>   non-field error as returned by Form.non_field_errors().
>
> The error argument can be a simple string, or preferably an instance
>   of ValidationError. See Raising ValidationError for best practices
>   when defining form errors.

You should check if there is no corresponding record in the database in the `clean` method of the `form` or before you call `form.is_valid()` in the view, and attach the error to the field:

```
form.addError("region", ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
```

*PS: To turn of the "yellow exception page" turn off `DEBUG` in your settings.*

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny, as there are more than just "region" one field, I need to check >2 fields if they existe data in database, so can I change this to form.addError("region","company", "start_date", ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))?

Comment: just check, and add several:`form.addError("region", ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))``form.addError("company", ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))`

Comment: Alternatively you can just do `form.addError(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists')` and it will appear as a non field error, which hopefully you are rendering in your template :)

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny, please see updated code, I added this and a " {{ form.non_field_errors }} " in html. But I was wondering still because in form there is drop down list, so the data must exist in database(unless users don't select anything). Just maybe the values from 2 fields don't match. For instance, car Model A does't exist in France, but in Germany. Do you think form.addError(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'), can check if the data row exists in database like select XX from XXX where A='' and B=''?

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny, I have tried the form.addError, but the error message still doesn't appear, I have put the question with a bounty, hope you could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you looping over formset? I assume you have `{% for form in formset %}` somewhere? Is this the most recent code? Please paste your entire template.

Comment: Also: adding the forms in the list view will have no effect, you have to add them in the form view.

Answer (score 3):

All this logic belongs inside the form itself. If you put it in the `clean` method, then the validation error will be caught by the existing Django logic and you can display the error in the template with `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: because I allow some fields to be blank, in this case I shouldn't use "{{ form.non_field_errors }}",right?

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this?

**views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
        region = form.cleaned_data['region']
        start_date=form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date=form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        ....          

        queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region,date__range=[start_date,end_date])

        try:
            result = Result.objects.get(region=region,supply_chain=supply_chain)
        except Result.DoesNotExist:
            result = None
```

**template.html**

```
{% if not result %} 
    <strong>No corresponding data exists</strong>
{% else %}
    {# display data #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks, {# display data #}, do you mean to put my original html body part  to replace "display data"? because I tried to put it in the end of body part, then it displays always"No corresponding..." . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you probably would want to place a for-loop there.

If the 'alert' is placed somewhere else in your html, you could instead of 'else' do:
{% if result %}

Comment: sorry I am still confused so I uploaded the html for your reference. Please correct me if I understand you in a wrong way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just start by saying that this answer is only reiterating what Daniel Roseman and Sebastian Wozny said in their answers so I'd encourage you to accept one of those over this.

Your `get_queryset` has one self-titled job, and that is to retrieve the queryset your form uses so it has no business doing any error handling at all.

That should be done in the form's `clean` method

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
    region = cleaned_data.get('region')
    country = cleaned_data.get('country')

    if not Result.objects.filter(region=region, country=country).exists():
         self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
```

Now what will happen, if your form isn't valid, you can then return to the same template with this form and it will contain errors about the fields that aren't valid.

Comment: really thanks a lot. I updated the code in "EDIT", but then in the "def get_queryset" couldn't get the "region" and "country" information entered in the form, if I gave a separate "def clean" method. Do you think if there is anything missing there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Elena - Why does it need to know whats in the form at all?

Comment: because the function of this code is to get what user has entered and then use their entry as a filter to filter the database to get result to display in a result page. That's why it is required to know what is in the form.

Comment: @Elena - I still think you're doing too much in your get queryset, your form can't possibly be valid if it has errors so there isn't any need to do any of this there.

Comment: Hi@Sayse, then come back to the question: in "EDIT" code returns "global name 'country'  is not defined", I suspect that in the "def get_queryset" doesn't get the form data, do you think I need to return anything in the "def clean(self)?

Comment: @Elena - No the clean doesn't return anything, it just validates the form, nothing else. Your `get_queryset` is looking in request.GET instead of `request.POST`. It may be worth using an IDE that lets you set breakpoints to see what your code is doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94193/discussion-between-elena-and-sayse).