# django 1.8 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

Tags: python, django

The error is self clear. But I was puzzled at how to solve it.

If the form entry get the corresponding record in the database, then there is no error. But if I enter something in the form that doesn't have corresponding data in the database, then it would appear the error of 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'aggregate'. I know the reason is because no query result, so in def context it cannot continue the calculation.

So if there is anyway if not finding corresponding record in the database, then it will not continue to do the calculation in "def get_context_data" to avoid this error? So the page will just remain on the current data entry page without redirecting to the another page to show the result.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages

class FinalView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'XXX'
    template_name = 'XXX.html'
    model = Final

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = InputForm(self.request.GET)        
        if form.is_valid():
            department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            person = form.cleaned_data['person']

            if department !="" and person !="":
                if Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person).exists():
                    queryset=Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person)
                    return queryset
                else:
                    form.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))

            elif department =="" and person !="":
                if Final.objects.filter(person=person).exists():
                    queryset=Final.objects.filter(person=person)
                    return queryset
                else:
                    form.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))

            elif ........


        else:     #if form not valid
            messages.error(request, "Error")

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

**EDIT as suggest**

```
.........Before are the same....

 def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        query_set = self.get_queryset()
        if query_set is not None:
            context = super(FinalView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context["sales"] = query_set.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
            return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that django query sets are are lazy to your advantage, it won't make a database query till it needs the data so just split it up to do some validation

```
query_set = self.get_queryset()
context = super(FinalView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
if query_set is not None:
    context['sales'] = query_set.aggregate(Sum('sales'))
return context
```

You may also want to make sure that all paths from `get_queryset` do actually return something to make this kind of validation easier.

Comment: thanks. After change, there is error of "local variable 'context' referenced before assignment", I will update the code as you suggest.

Comment: @Elena - I've updated to include where you should call super, regardless of what the queryset is you'll probably still want to call super

Comment: thanks. If there anything conflicts with "form.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))" in the def get_queryset(self), because I want to display the error message, but now is when the query is blank, it still doesn't display this error.

Comment: @Elena - Thats a different issue, its partly because your form goes out of scope when you exit the method but its also partly because thats not `get_querysets` job to do, all get queryset should be doing is what "it says on the tin" (getting a queryset).

Comment: thanks. I think I come back again to the question that you helped 1 week ago, but I still didn't solve that problem to display the error message on the form entry page when no record found. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494689/django-1-8-if-form-entry-query-result-doest-match-database-display-alert-mess.  How can I just display this error without redirecting to another page?

Comment: Well a `ListView` is still just a `View` so you should be able to handle it within the `def post` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95020/discussion-between-elena-and-sayse).