# How to check if an instance of a model already exist in database

Tags: python, django

So I defined a model `Language`. I need to track whoever created the language object. I also don't need multiple instances of the same language. For that reason I want to be able to check if a language already exists when a user tries to create one. If it exists then I'll just tell the user they can use the one already present. If not they can create it. I am using a custom `User` model.

```
USERS = get_user_model().objects.all()
from random import choice

class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chinemerem:language_index')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.language = self.language.upper()
        super(Language, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can create `Language` instances with `try/except` in `django` `shell` like below.

```
try:
    language, exists = Language.objects.get_or_create(creator=choice(USERS),
                                language='german')
except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

But `django admin` throws `IntegrityError` when I try to create a language instance through django admin.

**My question: How do I implement something like the `try/except` block above inside my model to check if a language already exists when a user tries to create one?**

I've done a lot of searching and have come across pre_save from [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) which I suspect might be helpful. But the django docs have very little by way of examples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make an Model manager and define a manager method that does the check to see if a matching language exists. You'll always need to save using the manager method in this case

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not create a queryset as module-level variable - you will end up with stale data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle "matching query does not exist" when getting an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119507/how-to-handle-matching-query-does-not-exist-when-getting-an-object)

Comment: Django's admin should already be checking for values that already exist since you have `unique=True` on the field. Have you done anything to override the form? Show your admin class.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I'm looking into it. Sounds like what I need.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for the warning. I only used that for demo.

Comment: @Sayse I'll look into that question and get back here when I'm done.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't touch the the form neither have a defined a custom model admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your problem comes from the way you call `get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) - you pass the two fields as lookup arguments, so it first try to find a `Language` with `language='german'` **and** `creator=<youruserhere>`. If the same language exists but with a different creator, it doesn't match the `where` clause so the orm tries to create a new record, and then the unique constraint on `language` kicks in.

The solution is to pass `creator` in a dict as `defaults` argument so the lookup is made on `language` only and `creator` is only used to create the new record if necessary:

```
language, created = Language.objects.get_or_create(
   # this is used for lookup (get)
   language="german", 
   # this is used for eventual create
   defaults={'creator':choice(USERS)}
   )
```

As a side note, the second element of the returned tuple will be `True` if a new record has been created and `False` if an already existing record was found.

wrt/ the problem in the admin, unless you did something strange in your `ModelAdmin` or it's form or you didn't post your whole model code, it should just redisplay the form with an error message, not raise an IntegrityError (unless eventually you get a race condition between form validation and instance save but that should be very very very rare). The uniqueness check during validation is a default feature of ModelForm so the only reason (I can think of) it would not be applied would be overridding your form's `clean()` method without calling `super().clean()`.

Comment: what I have up there is the whole model code. From your answer I get that you don't fully understand my question. Perhaps I didn't describe it well. But you've alerted me to the fact that I should only use **language** in calling `get_or_create` since that is my variable of interest, not the creator.

Comment: **...continuation...** But my problem is not with creating `Language` models in the `django` shell. The problem is that django admin complains that `UNIQUE constraint failed` when it tries to create an already existent language. Lets say for example a user *bruno* create a `Language` *german* for the first time. Later on another user *parousia* wants to create same *german* `Language`. Now there is a clash because *german* is `unique`. So the question is: **how do I check the `Language` table for  existence of *german* and exit gracefully if its already there?** *Graceful exit is what i seek*

Comment: @Parousia As already mentionned, unless you did something strange, django admin should just do the right thing here - redisplay the form with an error message. I just double-checked and it works out of the box. If you get a 500 error instead then there's something more to your code that you didn't post or something broken somewhere in your install (unless eventually you get a race condition between the form validation and the instance save, but that should be quite exceptional).

Comment: As as side note: you mention "your users" and "django admin" - unless by "your users" you mean "your site administrators" then you're doing it wrong, the Django admin has not been designed with end-users in mind, it's targeted at site administrators. But anyway: the unique check is not handled by the admin itself but by the ModelForm so it won't make any difference here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone. Here is how I solved the problem with a model manager.

I used two model managers. I used `objects = models.Manager()` as one of the model managers so that I won't need to rewrite a lot of my code.

```
from django.db import models
class LanguageManager(models.Manager):
    def language_exists(self, language):
        return super(LanguageManager, self).get_queryset().filter(language=language.upper()).exists()

class Language(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    languages = LanguageManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chinemerem:language_index')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.language = self.language.upper()
        if Language.languages.language_exists(self.language):
            return "Language already exists."
        else:
            super(Language, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exists method,

```
getLanguage = Language.objects.filter(language=request['langugage']).exists()

if not getLanguage:
 # create the model
```