# issue when running django site on IIS server

Tags: django, iis, server, modelform

I am new to django. I am facing an unusual error.

When I am running my site on localhost it is running smoothly. but when I run the same site via IIS server I am sometimes getting "Query doesn't exist issue".

It is same query when I run on localhost it always give a correct result but when run via IIS (1 out of 5 times) it give "query doesn't exist issue".

I have used try and except for the "query doesn't exist issue ". but can someone tell me why I am getting this issue. what should I add to the site.

I am not sure of what code to present. so please let me know and I will share the code.

Also I am using django modelforms to save the data.

Settings.py

```
    import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'o4=4a1-(*-f@4kv&$%(kfg$i3#kg8ut8=4_5e%s3r1juxs7r9k'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.81.73.37','127.0.0.1','vsapampz3-01']
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accnt_data.apps.AccntDataConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'accnt_profile.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates\AccountData') ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'accnt_profile.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Accounting',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Account1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Django_static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run migrations on the database on IIS? Show your complete `settings.py`

Comment: @SLDem Added complete settings.py to the question above. Also, yes, I ran all the migrations.

Comment: You can refer to the solution of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119507/how-to-handle-matching-query-does-not-exist-when-getting-an-object

Comment: @TheobaldDu I am using try and except to catch the "query doesn't exist" issue. But I am not getting the error while running the site on localhost. Only when I am running it via IIS server, I am getting the error. Want to know why only hosting via IIS, I am getting the issue.

Comment: Ok add your view with the query and related models please, also you need to set `PORT` to 5432 in your `DATABASES` setting, for the default postgresql port